# Implementing JS library in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components, render

I am using a javascript library called nextparticle. I am trying to implement it in React.js. I looked everywhere and tried all options but I can't get it to work.
I tried this.

```
import React, {Component } from 'react'
import { NextParticle } from '../nextparticle';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

    const Background = () => (
    <div>
        <Helmet>
            <script src="../nextparticle.js" type="text/javascript" />
        </Helmet>
        <NextParticle />
        </div>
  
);
```

This is the error I got

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I also tried `import NextParticle from '../nextparticle';`
Also doesn't work.
I've tried for days now. I should pass special params for this to work. Any params I try to put doesn't do anything.
This is how it should look like

```
   <img
  id="logo"
  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/23500/nextparticle.png"
/>

    <script src="https://nextparticle.nextco.de/nextparticle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      nextParticle = new NextParticle({
  image: document.all.logo,
  addTimestamp: true,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  initPosition: 'none',
  initDirection: 'none',
});
      });
      window.onresize = function () {
        if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
          nextParticle.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
          nextParticle.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
          nextParticle.start();
        }
      };
    </script>
```

I also added this in my index.html

```
<script src="/nextparticle.min.js"></script>
```

Again, no results.
this is the [documentation](https://nextparticle.nextco.de/documentation) for the library
Any Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can you share the documentation about that library please

Comment: here you go https://nextparticle.nextco.de/documentation

Comment: hello, i have coincidentally gotten into this same problem, i honestly don't know how to set up the NextParticle file, and you did not show how you set up yours, can i please see how you set it up? it would be really helpful

Comment: Hello @JeoffreyDuke, This works for me                         
`import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class Background extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "../nextparticle.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <img alt='logo' src={logo}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Background`I put the nextparticle js files in the public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I geuss you have to `export` your background component, as that is what the error is mentioning.

```
import React, {Component } from 'react'
import { NextParticle } from 'nextparticle';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

export const Background = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet>
        <script src="../nextparticle.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </Helmet>
    <NextParticle />
    </div>
  );
```

And if you want to import a third-party script in `React` import it directly in your `index.html` instead. Usually in the `public` directory. Unless you really need `Helmet`.

Comment: I am exporting the background component, I didn't show it here my bad. I also tried using it directly didn't work either. it says  NextParticle is not defined

Comment: Thank you robert, I just needed to add the js file in the public folder